# What does "we're all we've got" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, interpretation

In the movie *Ratatouille*, the father rat tells his son:

> Django: Take a good long look, Remy. Now, this is what happens when a rat gets a little too comfortable around humans. The world we live in belongs to the enemy. We must live carefully. We look out for our own kind, Remy. **When all is said and done, we're all we've got.**

I think I understand the last sentence, but it's still not clear to me. I can search for [when all is said and done](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/when%20all%20is%20said%20and%20done) (after considering or doing everything —used for a final general statement or judgment), but there is no result for "we're all we've got".

How would you rephrase that sentence?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the book "Case Studies in Child, Adolescent, and Family Treatment", page 253

> We (rats) have to stick together through everything

in another words,

> we are all we need

Answer (score 0):

"We" mean "the society of rats".

So "we're all we've got" means that rats can't expect anyone else to help them, especially not humans.

The father is telling Remi not to trust his human friend, only to trust other rats.

Answer (score 0):

In English, the expression to **have/have got something used with all** means:   to be able to enjoy or use something for one's own benefit or purpose for an inevitable or bad situation. It means: the only thing  you can rely on is X.

Other examples:
- All you've got [have] is five dollars in the bank!
- All you've got[have] is me.
- All he's got is his love of money.

**all someone has/has got grammatically can be understood as**:
- You **have nothing but** five dollars in the bank.
- You **have nothing else** but me.
- He **has nothing but** his love of money.

Therefore, the statement would go like this:
- **We're all we've got.**=
- We **have nothing but** ourselves.
- We **can rely on nothing** but ourselves.